# Why "missing", but not "needing" or "wanting"?

Tags: continuous-aspect, stative-verbs

The following sentence is OK:

> The table is missing a leg.

But the next two sentences sound a bit off (to my native ear, at least):

> The campaign is needing support.
>
> I am wanting an apple.

The verbs *need* and *want* are stative (i.e. denote a state), and so are generally incompatible with the Present Continuous. The verb *miss* in this context, however, denotes a state as well -- there is absolutely nothing dynamic going on.

**Why, then, does the sentence *"the table misses a leg"* sound wrong?**

Comment: "The table is wanting a leg" is entirely grammatical, meaning the same as *missing*.  But is it true that *"is needing a leg" sounds wrong.

Comment: I have heard *wanting* used like that.  I consider it to be colloquial, but nevertheless it is spoken in some parts. Same for *needing*.

Comment: You seem to ask one question in the title yet another the end of the body of your question?  Are you looking for the difference between missing/needing/wanting ? or are you wondering why to use "is missing" instead of "misses" ?

Comment: 'The table lacks a leg' sounds better if rather starchy. 'Be missing' with subject and object may perhaps be analysed as a transitive multi-word verb meaning 'lack'.

Answer (score 1):

'missing' implies that something should be there and isn't. The table should have a leg and doesn't, so it is missing one.

'Wanting' is almost always used nowadays for a person or other animate object that *desires* something. A table does not desire a leg. There is a different use of 'wanting', but it is archaic.

'Needing' is used when something is necessary for some purpose. That's not the same as something bring missing. I might *need* $20 to go to the movies, but I am not missing $20 (unless I previously had it).

Comment: great explanation of ~meanings~ but the OP looks to be asking a different question.  I asked him for clarifiction